# How to run python PyQt5 application in kiosk mode on Windows >= Win7

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pyqt5, pywin32

I wrote a PyQt5 application and I need to run it in kiosk-mode on Windows (I mean fullscreen with no title and window buttons and disabling as many as possible Windows shortcuts - i.e. Alt+Tab, etc.)

At the startup, the application:
- kills the explorer.exe using "taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe" so that no start menu or taskbar or sidebars are shown 
- use QMainWindow.showFullscreen() to show the application in fullscreen mode (with no window title and buttons)

with these steps, the application is shown as requested but I'm still able to switch to other opened applications using Alt+Tab shortcut.

I need a way at runtime to "block" this Alt+Tab shortcut (maybe others shortcuts needs to be blocked also, but lets focus on this one now).

I tried using an eventFilter in my application and watch for the shortcut but it seems the eventFilter does not recognize this shortcut (i.e. event.key() == Qt.Key_Tab and event.modifiers() == Qt.Key_Alt is always False).

Do you have any suggestion / best practices on how to do it?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I think you have to only set your app as shell and then nothing works on it - but I don't remember details as I did such set-up 10+ years ago on WinXP - but something similar should still work on current windows

Comment: hi @Drako , I also read about this, but I have no idea on how to do it... I read Microsoft's docs site but I found no practical example... if someone could point me to an example for this idea I'll try to implement it to see if it works

Comment: Sorry I can only google now same as you - as I said I did it 10+ years ago on XP so only expect to have similar possibility on newer win